# sharedPrefences и перенос данных

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

здравствуйте мне надо скачать данные из одной активности по методу Prefence и загрузить на вторую активность, но у меня на второй активности не работает кнопка приему и я не знаю почему...
я представил два кода, первый это откуда берутся данные ,а второй это куда они должны придти..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button save;
    Button load;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);

        load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        load.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                savePref();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                loadpref();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }}
        void savePref() {
            pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed= pref.edit();
            ed.putString("test",editText.getText().toString());
            ed.commit();
        }
        void loadpref(){
            pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String savetext = pref.getString("test","");
            editText.setText(savetext);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,trade.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

public class trade extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
EditText editText;
Button load;
SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trade);


    editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
    load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    load.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button4:
            loadpref();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
void loadpref(){
    pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = pref.getString("test","");
    editText.setText(s);
```

}}

Comment: Я же вам давал мануал по преференсам, но читать его вы, видимо, не хотели. getPreferences() работает только в пределах одной активити, для передачи МЕЖДУ активити используется getSharedPreferences()

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
```

Затем в

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    }
```

Потом метод сохранения данных и отправки

```
public void saveData(String key) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, editText.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Метод получения данных

```
private void getData(){
String textData = pref.getString(key, "");
ediText.setText(textData);
}
```